# How to prevent mocked external library function to be called internally unmocked

Tags: typescript, lambda, jestjs

We recently moved part of our codebase to a shared-package repo managed with lerna.

A part of this codebase contains our handlers, commandHandlers, queries, and so on.
Sometimes, to parse request, we use something we called `parseMultipartBody`. This needs the request to have a Content-Type property, so we mocked it in our jest setup file.

The problem is that in another test, we're testing a route calling a generic handler that uses that same method. The problem is that since it's called internally in the shared-package, it has no knowledge of jest and therefore asks for the Content-Type property, resulting in cascading errors in our tests.

So, how can we manage to "intercept" or prevent that internal call, without mocking the generic handler ?

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive research, it appears there's some kind of resolution by jest as to what is called.
The mocks I tried where targeting the exported function, so the path to the module was `@repo/handlers/utils`.

But targeting the file directly, in my case `@repo/handlers/utils/router/parseMultipartBody`, and mocking the specific function made it work.